# Certificate save Request WCF Webservice without DNS

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate

I have a Webservice running.
I have t0 access it with ip like "https://192.168.0.1:port/webservice" because the clients possibly have no DNS Server configured and i must not edit hosts File.

The Certificate is signed for the Webservice Hostname.
Its working fine, but certificate validator rejects hostname.

With Validationcallback it works normally.
Unfortuanally there is on Environement were I guess a paranoid Firewall or a Windowssetting which rejects the Certificate before my Callback can handle it.

With (testwise) Hosts Entry on Client Side it works.

Is there a way to 'fake' the ip by bypassing System DNS resolver and give an own IP for the endpoint but keep the requested URL like "https://webservice.mydomain.com:port/anything"?

Comment: The certificate is being validated by making a virtual connection on you machine to a local service and using TLS for validation.  So you are probably failing the validation due to the version of TLS that is being used.  TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are obsolete.  Normally TLS is used these days, but the new version TLS 1.3 may be needed.  TLS 1.3 uses an encryption mode that is not implemented on many machines.  You can check version of TLS using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and see what version(s) of TLS are being used.  The validation may try multiple TLS versions.

Comment: TLS Version is ok. It works with etc/hosts entry.

Comment: The encryption mode needs to be implemented on machine (see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).  Microsoft added a configuration property to either use TLS from Net or Operating System.  So in some cases it fails because the encryption mode is not in Net.  Other case when using operating system, the device doesn't support the encryption mode. So sometimes you have to change versions of Net, and other times for mobile devices (or windows) change versions.  You need to check certificate and see what encryption mode is being used.